# What happened to old identify-this-game or game-rec questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I just wonder what happened to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/who-is-the-guy-in-this-picture) which I asked some time ago. I was going to recall the name of the game, but apparently the question was deleted.

Comment: Your answer specifically is Commander Keen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was deleted as per updated site policies, which now prohibit any form of "identify-this-game" questions. The updated policy is reflected in the [site FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq), and you can read more about why it happened by [reading these meta-discussions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game).

In any case, your question was about Commander Keen, from the [Commander Keen series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_Keen) of games.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

We decided in the meantime that we really didn't want to do game identification any longer and deleted all such questions like we did for game-rec to retroactively enforce this - allowing us to make things work better going forward for new users